# So how can you really print colored text in c, on windows, using gcc?

Tags: c

I searched and tried some solutions, none worked.

1. ansi escape sequences - only works for unix-based
2. textcolor() (conio.h and curses.h) - only in turbo c++
3. graphic.h - doesn't really fix it, you'd have to change your .c files to .cpp every time

Is there a simple, or simple-ish, way to print color in c?

Comment: Seen [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5255355/How-to-Put-Color-on-Windows-Console) yet?

Comment: @JeffHolt this worked! Just curious, what does the modification does exactly?

Comment: It makes the console interpret the escape sequences instead of emitting them verbatim.

Comment: @JeffHolt Turns out using this isn't portable, I'm guessing because you need to run this command in order for it to work. If I'll attach a function to my program that run this command, can it damage certain functionalities in the pc I'm sending the .exe to?

Comment: Potentially change some other program's behavior? Yes. Likely? No, but that's just an opinion. If (a) some other program were emitting escape sequences like you want *your* program to emit and (b) the registry were not modified, then that other program would not be working either. Be that as it may, if you want to isolate changes only for your program', then [this](https://superuser.com/a/1300251/809697) will help you. All you have to do is use macros to compile a small amount of additional code when compiling for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Newer Windows can use the Unix way by enabling [Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences) in the console.

Older Windows need to use [`SetConsoleTextAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletextattribute). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers#character-attributes.

For example, if you want to turn text red, you'd do

```
#include "Windows.h"

void MakeRed() {
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED);
}
```